# Why is binding this DataGrid's ItemsSource to collection of anonymous types not working?

Tags: wpf, linq, datagrid, anonymous-types, itemssource

I have a collection of anonymous types that I wish to bind to the `ItemsSource` property of a `DataGrid`.  I confirmed the collection has items, but my `DataGrid` is empty.

I created a Debug converter and it does not hit my breakpoint in there so it appears something is going awry before that point.

I checked my Output window, and I see no binding errors.

My anonymous type looks something like this:

```
var cars = from c in something.Cars
           select new
           {
               Passengers = from p in c.Passengers
                            select new
                            {
                                 Name = p.Name
                            }
               Type = s.Type
            };
Cars = cars;
```

After this point, I checked the contents of Cars and it does have data.

My Xaml looks something like this:

```
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Cars}">
    <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Type}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
    <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Passengers}" >
                <!-- column definitions here -->
            </DataGrid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
</TabControl>
```

The `TextBlock` binding on Type does display the correct data.

What am I missing?

UPDATE:

The type of the linq result is `System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectListIterator`.  I have another `DataGrid`, where the binding to anonymous types work, but I noticed the linq result of type `System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`.

Comment: It's an IEnumerable.

Comment: you should .ToList() both the Passengers and the cars: `Passengers = c.Passengers.Select(x => x.Name).ToList()` and `Cars = cars.ToList()`

Comment: Also notice that if you're bringing this from Entity Framework you might need to `.Include()` the Passengers property in order for it to be populated with data.

Comment: @HighCore I tried calling ToList() but no luck :(